# socket.on callback repeat multiple times in socket.io swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sockets, socket.io

I'm using `pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 14.0.0'`
here is my socket manager file
I don't know why socketGetLatestMsg() callback repeat multiple times when I send message once this call one but after second message callback repeat twice after 3 msg callback repeat thrice and so on...
and go back to user lists inbox and come back to same user all repeated message show as it is but in database repeated message not save.

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = SocketIOManager(chatID: nil, token: nil);
    var socket: SocketIOClient?
    var manager: SocketManager?


    init(chatID: Int?, token: String?) {
        super.init();

        if chatID != nil && token != nil {
            manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: SOCKET_URL)!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .connectParams(["auth_token": token!, "user_id": chatID!])])

            self.socket = manager!.defaultSocket;

        } else if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userID") != nil && UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "authToken") != nil {

            manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: SOCKET_URL)!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .connectParams(["auth_token": UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "authToken") as! String, "user_id": UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userID") as! Int])])
            self.socket = manager!.defaultSocket;
        }

        self.socket?.connect();


    }


    //MARK:- All Emit
    func socketInboxEmit(userID: Int?,dictData: [String: Any]?) {
        if dictData != nil {

            self.socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: { (data, ack) in
                self.socket?.emit("chatroom.inbox", dictData!);

                self.getInboxList(chatID: userID);
                print("get Inbox socket List");
            })

        }
    }

    func socketGetUsrMsgEmit(chatListID: Int?, userID: Int?, dictData: [String: Any]?) {
        if chatListID != nil && dictData != nil && userID != nil {
            self.socket?.emit("chatroom.messages", dictData!);
            self.socketGetAllMsg(userID: userID, chatListID: chatListID!);
        }
    }

    func socketSaveMsg(chatListID: Int, dictData: [String: Any]?) {

        //self.socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: { (data, ack) in
            self.socket?.emit("save_message", dictData!);
            self.socketGetLatestMsg(chatListID: chatListID);
            print("socket connected");
        //})

    }



    func contactListEmit(dictData: [String: Any]?) {
        self.socket?.emit("chatroom.friends", dictData!);
    }


    //MARK:- Get All Data
    func socketCallBack(chatID: Int?, token: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (String, [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
        if chatID != nil {
            completionHandler("Fail", nil)
        }
        else {
            print("chat id not match or nil");
        }

    }

    func socketGetLatestMsg(chatListID: Int?) {
        socket?.on("chatroom.\(chatListID!)", callback: { (data, ack) in

            for filterData in data {
                if ((filterData as? [String: Any]) != nil) {
                    ChatVM.sharedInstance.appendNewMsg(responseDict: filterData as! JSONDictionary)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tblReload"), object: nil, userInfo: ["table": "reload"])
                } else {
                    print("Ok")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func socketGetAllMsg(userID: Int?, chatListID: Int) {
        self.socket?.on("chat.\(userID!).room.\(chatListID)", callback: { (data, ack) in
            for filterData in data {
                if ((filterData as? [String: Any]) != nil) {
                    ChatVM.sharedInstance.parseChatListData(responseDict: filterData as! JSONDictionary)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tblReload"), object: nil, userInfo: ["table": "reload"])
                } else {
                    print("Ok")
                }
            }


        })
    }

    func getInboxList(chatID: Int?) {

        socket?.on("user.\(chatID!).chatinbox", callback: { (data, ack) in

            for filterData in data {
                if ((filterData as? [String: Any]) != nil) {


                    ChatVM.sharedInstance.parseInboxListData(responseDict: filterData as! JSONDictionary);

                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tblInboxReload"), object: nil);
                    //completionHandler("Success", filterData as? [String : Any])
                } else {
                    print("Ok")
                    //completionHandler("Fail", nil)
                }
            }
        })

    }


    func getContactList(userID: Int?) {
        socket?.on("user.\(userID!).friends", callback: { (data, ack) in

            for filterData in data {
                if ((filterData as? [String: Any]) != nil) {

                    ChatVM.sharedInstance.parseFriendListData(responseDict: filterData as! JSONDictionary)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "tblPendingReload"), object: nil, userInfo: filterData as! [AnyHashable : Any])
                    //completionHandler("Success", filterData as? [String : Any])
                } else {
                    print("Ok")
                    //completionHandler("Fail", nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func closeSocket() {
        self.socket?.disconnect();
    }

    func activeSocket() {
        self.socket?.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into this issue, were you able to solve it?